# CSS Modules and CSS keyframe animations

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, css-modules

I am trying to do a simple animation using React, keyframes, CSS modules (and SASS). The problem is that CSS Modules hash keyframe names the same way it hashes the local classes.

JS code

```
//...

export default () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  return(
    <div className={active ? 'active' : 'inactive'}
      onClick={() => setActive(!active)}
    >content</div>
  )
}
```

An attempt to make everything global, used [this](https://gravitydept.com/blog/keyframe-animations-in-css-modules) source as a tutorial (does not compile):

```
//default scope is local

@keyframes :global(animateIn) {
  0% { background: black; }
  100% { background: orange; }
}

@keyframes :global(animatOut) {
  0% { background: orange; }
  100% { background: black; }
}

:global {
  .active {
    background: orange;

    animation-name: animateIn;
    animation-duration: 1s;
  }

  .inactive {
    background: black;

    animation-name: animateOut;
    animation-duration: 1s;
  }
}
```

Changing this does not work too:

```
:global {
  @keyframes animateIn {
    0% { background: black; }
    100% { background: orange; }
  }

  @keyframes animateOut {
    0% { background: orange; }
    100% { background: black; }
  }
}
```

Another attempt (does not work):

```
@keyframes animateIn {
  0% { background: black; }
  100% { background: orange; }
}

@keyframes animateOut {
  0% { background: orange; }
  100% { background: black; }
}

:global {
  .active {
    background: orange;

    :local {
      animation-name: animateIn;
    }
    animation-duration: 1s;
  }

  .inactive {
    background: black;

    :local {
      animation-name: animateOut;
    }
    animation-duration: 1s;
  }
}
```

How to use keyframes in CSS modules global scope? Is it possible to use local scope keyframes in a global scope class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your third attempt was almost fine, you just have to add `&` before `:local` and make sure there's a space in between them. By doing so, you switch to the local scope within the selector.

```
:global {
    .selector {
        & :local {
            animation: yourAnimation 1s ease;
        }
    }
}

@keyframes yourAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Which compiles to

```
.selector {
    animation: [hashOfYourAnimation] 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: It worker without a space too, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The original answer works just fine. This works without SASS:

```
:global {
    .selector {
        // global selector stuff ...
    }

    .selector :local {
        animation: yourAnimation 1s ease;
    }
}

@keyframes yourAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the animation name in the component like this:

```
  <div
      style={{
        animationName: styles.animationName
      }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case nothing of above solutions worked, but I found `css-loader` parses all camelCased words and parses them, so I changed my `@keyframes` animation name to snake_case and that worked!...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using LESS this hack makes the above hack work:

```
@keyframes ~":global(ANIMATION-NAME)" {
  // Keyframes description.
}
```

https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/115#issuecomment-372909009